# Magento: Failed to load static resource - When language is not default (en_US)

Tags: magento

After install Magento on localhost

Following [this instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-magento-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Magento can't load css, javascript (static files)

[image]

After some research i knew that i must run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, so i did

```
cd /var/www/html/magento
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

The tool deploy a lot of statics files

```
$:/var/www/html/magento$ sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Requested languages: en_US
Requested areas: frontend, adminhtml
Requested themes: Magento/blank, Magento/luma, Magento/backend
=== frontend -> Magento/blank -> en_US ===
=== frontend -> Magento/luma -> en_US ===
=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> en_US ===
................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2136 files; errors: 0
---

........................................................
Successful: 2061 files; errors: 0
---

............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2012 files; errors: 0
---

=== Minify templates ===

Successful: 869 files modified
---

New version of deployed files: 1494363632
```

But load static resource still failing

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /magento/pub/static/version1494362497/frontend/Magento/luma/pt_BR/css/print.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This magento are set to use `pt_BR` as language, run 'sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy' deploy the static resources to default language (en_US)

The tool needs a extra param to specify this

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_BR
```

output:

```
Requested languages: pt_BR
Requested areas: frontend, adminhtml
Requested themes: Magento/blank, Magento/luma, Magento/backend
=== frontend -> Magento/blank -> pt_BR ===
=== frontend -> Magento/luma -> pt_BR ===
=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> pt_BR ===
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2012 files; errors: 0
---

.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2061 files; errors: 0
---

..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2136 files; errors: 0
---

=== Minify templates ===

Successful: 869 files modified
---

New version of deployed files: 1494363897
```